# How to combine ASP.NET webpages site with a MVC 6 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-webpages, webmatrix-3

I have heard that MVC 6 is combination of Webpages, MVC and Web API. I want to know how to combine a ASP.NET Webpages Content in MVC 6. I want to merge a Webpages site (developed using Webmatrix) into MVC 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebPages are not yet supported in ASP.NET 5. It is scheduled for [Q3 2016](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#future-work). You can find more details in [ASP.NET 5 Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap)